# Use the Chrome Devtools Console Filter to hide console errors caused by extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, web-development, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to remove all the `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` errors I get due to AdBlock, so I thought the `Filter` field would be appripriate but I can't use it to reverse filter.

[image]

Basically what I want is `... | grep -v ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer, please go to chrome bug tracker and let the chrome dev team know we need this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239401

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Nowadays Chrome has an exclusion mechanism in its filter box:

```
-net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

This removes all console errors that block access to network resources. These errors are usually caused by ad blockers and similar scripts. But watch out, this can also be caused by service workers on your own site.

As a more thorough solution, you might want to block the output generated by all extensions. This also leaves less chance for false positives.

Located at the top-right corner of the console there's a cog wheel to manage console settings. The option `Selected context only` ignores all of the nested browser extension contexts. Below some example screenshots.

Settings with `Selected context only` disabled:

[image: Settings with "Selected context only" disabled]

Settings with `Selected context only` enabled:

[image: Settings with "Selected context only" enabled]

Comment: `(?!.*BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)` is sufficient (for the superlazyuser).

Comment: No, it doesn't. Did you turn on regex? And did you check other output not being deleted as well? Your solution filters out all console output when regex is disabled, and filters nothing when regex is enabled.

Comment: Chrome changed the way this works, you'll need to surround the regex with forward slashes: `/^(?!net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT).*$/`

Comment: how do I hide the following message `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: That looks like an error from a specific website. Just filtering the error doesn't seem like a great idea. If you're really sure you want to filter that, you could do this: `/^(?!lastError: Could not establish connection\. Receiving end does not exist\.).*$/`

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Chromium 72. Filtering is applied only right after typing the rule, but after a refresh/navigation it's no longer effective. Bug? Ideas?

Comment: It seems Chrome has removed this functionality. As a work-around you can enable "Selected context only" to disable all logging bij extensions. This option can be found under the settings cog in the console.

Answer (score 37):

Mac Pro  (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
OSX: 10.10.5
Chrome: 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit)

1. Open '**Console**' and right click on the **Error log** you do not want to see.
2. Click on '**Filter**'-> '**Hide message from** *xxx.js*'

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Also working nicely on Windows.

Comment: but fails with source maps (all messages are from one huge `vendor.js`)

Comment: How do you cancel that? I believe I just clicked it by mistake and I don't see any filter enabled. => Ok, found it, gotta click on another message -> filter -> unhide all

Comment: Cannot find "unhide all" on the last Chrome version...

Answer (score 5):

I found that right-clicking on each message allows to hide it, but this doesn't work for scripts with autogenerated file names.

[image: right click in dev console to hide a script]

**Edit**: There is a "hide network messages" option now (the gods of Google Chrome answered our prayers :D):

*Before*:

[image: Before]

*After*:

[image: After]

Comment: Am I crazy, or did the ability to do this go away in the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: Still here in Chrome 35

Comment: I'm on Mac. Maybe that's a difference?

Comment: I'm on Mac too ;)

Comment: Looks like I'm crazy. Weird. When I right click all I get is the "Unhide All" option greyed out. No list of files.

Comment: You have to right click on a particular error message to hide errors from the script that generated it (yeah weird for me too)

Comment: Thing to note is that the "hide network messages" solution does filter out ALL network messages, including failed API calls on your own site. Which makes debugging quite hard.

Answer (score 2):

While it is less specific, I find that I can click the gear icon and check the "Hide Network" checkbox. What's more, this setting persists for new instances of the console and across restarts. Filters do not.

So while the filter is good if you just want to shut it off temporarily, this option removes these errors by default.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You cannot filter out console errors (in red) using the filter option.</s>

Your best option is to either wait for an update of the extension which solves the problem, or find an alternative extension that does the same thing, or manually download the extension, unpack it, change the code that causes the error, then pack it back and install it.

Recent versions of Chrome seem to have reverse filter as mentioned in [Guido Bouman's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/737390/use-the-chrome-devtools-console-filter-to-hide-console-errors-caused-by-extensio/1028554#1028554).

Comment: Thanks I guess I will just wait, I found that right clicking on each error message can allow me to "hide" them, but most of the files are analytics files (blocked by AdBlock) and the file names are auto generated but this method works for only a few analytics providers.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing for me(( Chrome version 36, Windows 8
[image: clicked exactly on a log message many times]

Answer (score 0):

Note that, inside the Filter input box, you can also add a string of negative matches that will prevent messages beginning with those characters from displaying.

Example:

```
-WARNING -Errorcode -bonk
```

Will suppress messages like the following:

```
WARNING line 234 something else on this line
This message will still display
Errorcode 234: Some error that will be hidden
bonk
```

The only message from the above that would display is:

```
This message will still display
```